# PIVOT TRANSFORM in MSAccess

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

In MSAccess I have a table with column

```
1 Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4.
```

I want to make this column as rows as shown below using an SQL query preferably using PIVOT TRANSFORM. Any help is appreciated!

```
1 Col1,
2 Col2
3 Col3
4 Col4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a UNION or UNION ALL query:

```
Select 1, Col1 From MyTable
Union All
Select 2, Col2 From MyTable
Union All
Select 3, Col3 From MyTable
Union All
Select 4, Col4 From MyTable
```

Union All will return rows from every table even if it creates duplicates. Union will effectively group the results together so that you can unique rows at a performance cost.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. Are there any performance issues if I use Union? Do you have any idea about applying pivoting in this case?

Comment: @Vin - Depends on the amount of data. For most systems, the performance difference will not be significant, however if the table is very large (so you are union'ing a lot of data together), it might make a difference. The real question is whether what you need is to not have duplicates and whether duplicates are possible. If that is true, then using Union is the right answer.

Comment: As to duplicates, UNION ALL includes them, UNION removes them (and will take more time to return results). As to the performance question in general, if all you're doing is returning the results in a form or a report, there really isn't one. But if you're wanting to apply a WHERE clause to the aggregate set, then you've got a performance bottleneck, since the indexes cannot be used. In that case, you'd be better off with a WHERE clause that checks all four fields (with `OR`).